# How to seek video when playing from MediaSource

Tags: javascript, html5-video, media-source

I followed this guide: https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/netfix/blob/gh-pages/demo/bufferWhenNeeded.html

When the user selects a play point on the progress bar.

will call seek() to return the corresponding data
then append the data to sourceBuffer,

```
    function seek(e) {
        const start = (Math.round((totalFileSize / video.duration) * video.currentTime));
        const end = (start + Math.round(start / 5));
        fetchRange(assetURL, start, end);
    };

    function fetchRange(url, start, end) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('get', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=' + start + '-' + end);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            console.log('fetched bytes: ', start, end);
            bytesFetched += end - start + 1;
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(chunk);
        };
        xhr.send();
    };
```

however i always get an error:

"`Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': The HTMLMediaElement.error attribute is not null`."

I really searched a lot but couldn't solve it,

I'm really grateful someone can help.

Comment: What file format are you using? Usually you must seek to keyframes so check how your format stores keyframes and append from there. Don't just slice any bytes and append because the starting bytes might be wrong (_eg:_ is not some header bytes giving info about this next video frame)

Comment: @VC.One I use file format .mp4 (Fragmented MP4)